# Why is the variable in my php resetting itself to zero?

Tags: php, variables

This was a typo question and I didn't really want to leave my code up here.  It would not benefit anyone else.

This is my code and I want the variable $x to be itself plus the value of $points.  For some reason, this is the output I get:

```
TOTAL Before Add: 0
points: 8
TOTAL after add: 8

TOTAL Before Add: 0
points: 32
```

TOTAL after add: 32

I want this to make x: 40 (adding 8+32).

Why is x starting over at 0 again every time?

Appreciate the help,
R

Comment: I'm pretty certain that can't be (`$x` is not assigned in the loop and not passed to anything which could modify it by reference). Your real code is likely different.

Comment: Is it a typo that you assign `$row3` in the while condition and later access `$row4`?

Comment: I put in the real code so you could understand what was happening.  The row numbers was not a typo.  I was just running loops inside each other and using data from the previous row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code, you confuse `$row3` and `$row4`, but I'll assume you're iterating over one row here. Also, you seem to present a heavily abstracted version here. Verify that the bug appears even after the simplification, for example with a test database. But assuming that's not the case, the only explanation is:

You're executing the whole code snippet multiple times. Each time it is executed, it reads exactly one line. Add

```
echo "Start of loop, x: $x";
```

before the while and you'll see two runs.

As a final note, you should really only use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) in post-2010 code. It is database-independent and has excellent support for transactions and prepared statements.

---

In response to the edit:

First of all, your code is **vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection)**. Fix that now, for example by using PDO prepared statements.

Secondly, why are you joining in php code? You should calculate the sums and all the data you need on the database, with multiple [JOINs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)). You should not need more than one(maybe two) SQL query for that.

Thirdly, the problem is that you're not adding to $total:

```
$total=$Total+$points;
```

Since `$Total` is undefined, it's evaluated as `0`, so you could equally write:

```
$total = $points;
```

Of course, you wanted:

```
$total += $points;
```

But as I mentioned above, it's still an extremely bad coding style to perform trivial calculations (such as summing up) in the application instead of the database.

Comment: I'll look into it.  I know the code is running multiple times and I want to keep adding to x (now called Total) each time the loop runs.  I originally assign x=0 before the loop runs so I figured if I add to it within the loop, the value it was assigned the last time through would be maintained and it would continue to increase.  Instead it seems to reset to zero every time the loop runs.

Comment: @Rossi Well, I'd strongly assume that it's not the php interpreter messing up, but your program. Than there are three logical explanations: 1. You keep adding 0 or don't add anything. This is not the case. 2. There is a logical error in your code. This is the case. 3. The loop gets called multiple times.

Comment: I am aware that it was a problem in the code.  I was wondering if anyone could help me see it.  Yes, the loop does get called multiple times.  This is good what I want.

Comment: @Rossi Please see the updates in the body of this answer, in particular about using one (or two) SQL statements instead of four, and the capitalization of `$total`.

Comment: Yup, that was a typo - stupid capitalization problem. Thanks so much.  I know, it is vulnerable and apparently bad style but I've been teaching this stuff to myself and using whatever comes up in Google basically.  So, now I know to look into PDO.  Thanks!